# Jolt transformation to retrieve key as value

Tags: jolt

I have this JSON input that I would like to transform via jolt spec

```json
{
  "message": {
    "trx": {
      "trxId": "1234"
    },
    "translation": {
      "transactions": {
        "1234": "http://www.trythisjolt.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

expected output would be something like this

```json
{
  "message": {
    "trx": {
      "trxId": "1234",
      "trxName": "http://www.trythisjolt.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Is this achievable with Jolt please? I have tried several possibilities but I'm very new to Jolt and have not managed so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes achievable, you can use

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "trxId": "message.trx.&",
          "transactions": { "*": "message.trx.trxName" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where go to the innermost elements firstly, then prepend `message.trx.` for both while renaming the second one to the desired value. This way, both of them are nested within the common object.

Comment: Thank you @Barbaros Ozhan. That worked like a charm.

Comment: you're welcome @steveciantar , have nice studies. Btw, your little daughter is so cute that God bless her.